# How to map array of nested types

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to define an index that has an array of nested types. However whenever I insert a document I can't get any results doing a nested query.

I have the following mapping defined:

```
 curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/product/_mapping -d '{
    "product": {
       "properties": {
          "properties": {
             "type": "nested"
          }
       }
    }
 }'
```

But when I add an item:

```
  curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/product/1432008 -d '{
     "properties": [
        {
           "data_type": 0,
           "id": 19,
           "name": "Vendor",
           "value": "TEST TEST",
           "value_id": 16577846
        }
     ]
  }'
```

I get the following:

```
 {
    "test": {
       "product": {
          "properties": {
             "properties": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                   "data_type": {
                      "type": "long"
                   },
                   "id": {
                      "type": "long"
                   },
                   "name": {
                      "type": "string"
                   },
                   "value": {
                      "type": "string"
                   },
                   "value_id": {
                      "type": "long"
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Which actually looks correct. However I get 0 hits for the following:

```
 curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/test/product/_search -d '
 {
   "query": {
     "filtered": {
       "query": {"match_all": {}},
       "filter": {
         "nested": {
           "path": "properties",
           "query":{
             "filtered": {
               "query": { "match_all": {}},
               "filter": {
                 "and": [
                   {"term": {"properties.name": "vendor"}},
                   {"term": {"properties.value": "test test"}}
                 ]
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }'
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/test/product/_search -d '
 {
   "query": {
     "filtered": {
       "query": {"match_all": {}},
       "filter": {
         "nested": {
           "path": "properties",
           "query":{
             "filtered": {
               "query": { "match_all": {}},
               "filter": {
                 "and": [
                   {"term": {"name": "Vendor"}},
                   {"term": {"value": "TEST"}}
                 ]
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized what is going on here. In my example above I changed it a bit to hide business details. I left out that the term filter had a value with a space in it "test test". The space got. Me. Thanks for your help.